# clang-tidy cmake exclude file from check

Tags: cmake, static-analysis, cppcheck, clang-tidy

I have a dependency as source in my project that I have no control over.
I'm using cmake's clang-tidy integration to analyze my code, and this dependency is firing A LOT of warnings. Is there a way to tell cmake not to run clang-tidy on specific files ?
I tried to add the files to the `-line-filter` option of clang-tidy, but this doesn't work:

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES
CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${clang_tidy_loc};\
${TIDY_CONFIG} \
-line-filter=\"[\
{\"name\":\"path/to/file.cpp\"},\
{\"name\":\"path/to/file.h\"}\
]\"")
```

If the solution could work with other static analyzers like cppcheck it would be really nice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If some property - like `CXX_CLANG_TIDY` - is only available on target level, you have to move the files you want to have different settings for into a separate new target itself.

This can be done by using [`OBJECT` libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries).

In your case something like:

```perl
add_library(
    target_no_static_code_analysis
    OBJECT
        path/to/file.cpp
        path/to/file.h
)

# NOTE: Resetting only needed if you have a global CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY
set_target_properties(
    target_no_static_code_analysis
    PROPERTIES
         CXX_CLANG_TIDY ""
)

...
add_library(target ${other_srcs} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:target_no_static_code_analysis>)
```

**References**

- [CMake/Tutorials/Object Library](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library)

Comment: I didn't think about that yesterday but this seems so obvious now. Thanks for the clear and well documented answer, if it's a dependency it should have already been a different target...

Comment: Learned about OBJECT library thanks to this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a header only library I use **SYSTEM** (should also be possible for OBJECT libraries)

```
add_library(
  header_only_library_no_static_code_analysis 
  INTERFACE
)

target_include_directories(
  header_only_library_no_static_code_analysis 
  SYSTEM # Adds -isystem instead of -I and this tells clang-tidy not to analyze these includes
  INTERFACE
    path/to
)
```

I couldn't use this approach for a long time due to following bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1698539

But with GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain Version 9-2020-q2-update it seems resolved :)

Comment: This is liable to trigger https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/llvmlibc-restrict-system-libc-headers.html