# CMake passes all gcc flags to nvcc as well

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, compiler-flags, linker-flags

My project uses cuda kernel for a small module and needs nvcc for compiling. During compilation, cmake pass the same linker and compiler flags intended for gcc to nvcc as well. In my particular case, I get the following error.

```
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'Wl,--no-as-needed'
```

Following the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344564/cmake-remove-a-compile-flag-for-a-single-translation-unit) thread, I managed to remove the compiler flags for the target that needs nvcc as follows.

```
get_target_property(_target_cxx_flags target_that_needs_nvcc COMPILE_OPTIONS)
list(REMOVE_ITEM _target_cxx_flags "-fcolor-diagnostics")
```

Using this, I avoided the errors due to wrong compiler flags like this:

```
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'fdiagnostics-color'
```

But I cannot use the same procedure to remove linker flags because `get_target_property` fetches only compiler flags and not linker flags.

I am looking for a solution to disable the linker flags for just one target compilation.

The cmake minimum version expected is `VERSION 3.0`

Comment: There are many target properties that *may* contain the flags you want to remove. Have you tried `LINK_FLAGS` or `LINK_OPTIONS`? There is a comprehensive list of target properties [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets). Perhaps, they are in `INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS`?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to removing flags you don't want is to never add them in the first place.  You can be language-specific using generator expressions.  eg:

```
add_compile_options("$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${my_cxx_flags}>")
add_compile_options("$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:${my_cuda_flags}>")
```

I realise you're asking about linker flags not compiler flags, but hopefully this might set you off in a useful direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I am not setting these flags myself in my CMakeLists.txt file. I am inheriting these from the root CMakeLists.txt and I am trying not to tamper with it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is to turn off the propagation of flags from gcc to nvcc.
Take a look at the option `CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS` in the legacy cuda support variable in the find cuda module.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ```CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS```. It helps to remove compiler flags (I don't need ```get_target_property``` to remove ```fdiagnostics-color``` anymore). Unfortunately, it doesn't do any change to the linker flags and my issue still exists.