# CMAKE - check if target is compilable

Tags: cmake

My project consists of multiple targets. I want to specify compile options for all of them with
command "target_compile_options"

I get a list of targets using macros from [CMake - remove a compile flag for a single translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344564/cmake-remove-a-compile-flag-for-a-single-translation-unit):

```
macro(apply_global_cxx_flags_to_all_targets)
    separate_arguments(_global_cxx_flags_list UNIX_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
    get_property(_targets DIRECTORY PROPERTY BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
    foreach(_target ${_targets})
        target_compile_options(${_target} PUBLIC ${_global_cxx_flags_list})
    endforeach()
    unset(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)
    set(_flag_sync_required TRUE)
endmacro()
```

But I receive errors:

> target_compile_options called with non-compilable target type

as some of targets doesn't require compiling. Is there a way to check if project is compilable? I want to use "target_compile_options as I need to remove some options for one subproject (as in mentioned thread)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to check if project is compilable?

Yes, get the type of the target and check if it's an executable or a library and if it's not an INTERFACE library.

> I want to specify compile options for **all of them**

Consider using `add_compile_options` at root folder instead.