# How to change some CMAKE_C_FLAGS for just one executable in CMake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, cross-platform

I have a CMake project that supports multiple platform combination (arm, powerpc ,x86-64). Native platform is x86-64.

I have toolchain.cmake file for each cross-platform build(for arm and powerpc).
When I give toolcahin.cmake files for cross-platform build  to cmake  everything is working as expected except one thing.

In the project I want to build a particular executable with native build support(that is on x86-64). Since I gave toolchain.cmake file explicitly, so all CMAKE_C_FLAGS are global for all executable in project.

So I want to give toolchain.cmake(say for arm) to cmake and want to build the whole project except one executable on native(x86-64) in one go.
Is there any way where I can change the complete CMAKE_C_FLAGS and can provide the native one for that particular executable ?

I tried few things as per [How to change a compiler flag for just one executable in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238937/how-to-change-a-compiler-flag-for-just-one-executable-in-cmake) but can't get the solution to this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CMake with multiple compilers for the same language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542971/using-cmake-with-multiple-compilers-for-the-same-language)

Comment: In CMake project you cannot build executables both for the host and for the target at once. You need to use several `cmake` invocations (with different toolchains and so).