# How to set compiler flags in cmakelists.txt of single file for debug or release ?

Tags: cmake

I have found the way to configure according to Andre's comment in [How to change a compiler flag for just one executable in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238937/how-to-change-a-compiler-flag-for-just-one-executable-in-cmake) .

For example, I add a flag for bubble.c:

```
set_source_files_properties( ${ProjDirPath}/../bubble.c PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-O2")
```

It worked.But I can't specify the flag for debug or release.
Dose anyone know how to configure it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)
set_source_files_properties( ${ProjDirPath}/../bubble.c PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-O2")
ENDIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES DEBUG)
```

Comment: Only works for single-configuration generators per cmake documentation for the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

Use special syntax like this:

```
set_source_files_properties(myfile.cpp PROPERTIES 
    COMPILE_FLAGS $<$<CONFIG:RelDebug>:/O2>
    SKIP_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS $<$<CONFIG:RelDebug>:ON>
)
```

Sets specific compilation option only to specific configuration (in this case for `RelDebug`).