# Add "-fobjc-arc" flag on specific files from command line

Tags: xcode, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working on a non-arc workspace,for specific files I added "-fobjc-arc" flag **BuildPhases>CompileSources>**. When I try to automate the build I'm unable to add the compiler flags. I have multiple targets, so i should pick the required target and add compiler flags for files in the target. Can it be handled while generating the project with **CMAKE**?
Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using "xcodebuild", Initially cmake generates the xcode project with no flags, here before building the project i should add the flags. When i said I have a added flags in build phases, then i was building the whole project manually

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13639476/629118 ?

Comment: thank you for the link. Will add the mentioned commands and check accordingly.