# clang 4.0.0 cuda and cmake best practices for minimal warnings

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, clang, clang++

I can't figure out how to get `clang` CUDA specific flags for only CUDA files:

```
# building all except 20
set(BUILD_CUDA_ARCH "30;32;35;50;52;53")

# According to the docs, we need static cudart:
# http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html#compiling-cuda-code
list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS "cudart_static")

# Let clang know exactly where cuda came from
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --cuda-path=${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}")

# Add the compilation trajectories for different architectures
# go to the docs linked above
foreach(arch ${BUILD_CUDA_ARCH})
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_${arch}")
endforeach()

# Add the executable like normal, now that CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS has been adjusted.
# clang will compile the .cu files separately
add_library(${LIB_NAME} ${LIBRARY_TYPE} ${CXX_INC} ${CXX_SRC} ${CUDA_INC} ${CUDA_SRC})
```

Where elsewhere in the file is defined

- `LIB_NAME`: the name of the library being built
- `LIBRARY_TYPE`: either `SHARED` or `STATIC`
- `CXX_INC` and `CXX_SRC`: pure C++ headers / source code
- `CUDA_INC` and `CUDA_SRC`: straight CUDA code
- `EXTRA_LIBS`: just used in `target_link_libraries` with other stuff

The problem is that this approach results in:

```
clang-4.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_30' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-4.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_32' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-4.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_35' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-4.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_50' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-4.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_52' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-4.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_53' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

warnings for *every* non-cuda compilation.  Do I **have** to separate this out into two separate libraries, or is there some way of telling `clang`?  The [linked docs in the comments](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html#compiling-cuda-code) seem to indicate that it should only be doing cuda stuff with `.cu` files, but I can't seem to find specific flags for only that mode.  It feels awkward to split it into two libraries with how things are split up logically - the CPU version includes different files that effectively do the same thing w/o the gpu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the CUDA compilation flags as cmake compilation properties only for CUDA source files, rather than adding them unilaterally and then trying to suppress them selectively.

Comment: Lol DUH that's way better, since I already have a list of which files need to be setup for CUDA, only add the CUDA flags to them!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to ignore it as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13639476/3814202)

```
# Squelch warnings about cuda flags for C++ files
foreach(cxx ${CXX_SRC} ${CXX_INC})
  set_source_files_properties(${cxx} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -Wno-unused-command-line-argument)
endforeach()
```

I don't think it's appropriate to give a blanket `-Wno-unused-command-line-argument`, but it seems likely separate treatment of flags is not in `llvm`.