# Dynamic Analysis with Clang - Suppressing Reports in External Libraries Ignored in a CMake project

Tags: cmake, qt5, c++14, clang++, ctest

I am trying to use `-fsanitize=address` [feature](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#suppressing-reports-in-external-libraries) in clang compiler, but I am interested in to see my local project errors only, so I will ignore the incoming error from 3rdparty libraries, specifically I have a project configured to ignore the errors who become from dbus.

My system:
cmake version 3.9.5

Linux hostname 4.14.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.7-1 (2017-12-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux

clang version 4.0.1-8 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

My [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CTestConfig.cmake
├── CTestCustom.cmake
├── MyASan.supp
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── entityitem.cc
    ├── mainwindow.cc
    ├── mainwindow.h
    └── mainwindow.ui

1 directory, 10 files
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(SanitizerTest)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

CTestConfig.cmake:

```
## This file should be placed in the root directory of your project.
## Then modify the CMakeLists.txt file in the root directory of your
## project to incorporate the testing dashboard.
##
## # The following are required to submit to the CDash dashboard:
##   ENABLE_TESTING()
##   INCLUDE(CTest)

set(CTEST_PROJECT_NAME "Exampling")
set(CTEST_NIGHTLY_START_TIME "01:00:00 UTC")

set(CTEST_DROP_METHOD "http")
set(CTEST_DROP_SITE "localhost:8090")
set(CTEST_DROP_LOCATION "/submit.php?project=Exampling")
set(CTEST_DROP_SITE_CDASH TRUE)
```

CTestCustom.cmake:

```
set(CTEST_CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles")
set(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_TYPE "AddressSanitizer")
set(CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY ${CTEST_SCRIPT_DIRECTORY})
set(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE ${CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/MyASan.supp)
ctest_empty_binary_directory("${CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY}")
set(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_TYPE "AddressSanitizer")
ctest_start(Experimental)
set(CONFIGURE_OPTIONS
  "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"
  "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address"
  "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address"
  "-DCMAKE_GENERATOR=Unix Makefiles"
  "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang"
  "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang"
)
ctest_configure(OPTIONS "${CONFIGURE_OPTIONS}")
ctest_build()
```

MyASan.supp:

```
interceptor_via_lib:dbus-1
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
add_library(module
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mainwindow.cc)
target_include_directories(module INTERFACE
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/module_autogen/include>)
target_link_libraries(module
  PUBLIC stdc++
  PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)
add_executable(main
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/entityitem.cc)
target_link_libraries(main module)
```

src/entityitem.cc:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a{argc, argv};
  MainWindow d;
  qDebug() << d.width();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

src/mainwindow.cc:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
  int *i{new int};
  ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

src/mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  private:
    Ui::MainWindow ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

src/mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

My problem, from the project root dir execute:

```
mkdir build
cd build
ctest -DCTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY="." --verbose -S ../CTestCustom.cmake
./src/main
```

And then the output is:

```
    =================================================================
    ==24262==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

    Direct leak of 6912 byte(s) in 27 object(s) allocated from:
        #0 0x4d0810  (/home/adacosta/WORK/fffffffffff/Sanitazer/build/src/main+0x4d0810)
        #1 0x7f75480378ed  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1+0x1d8ed)

    Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
        #0 0x4d0810  (/home/adacosta/WORK/fffffffffff/Sanitazer/build/src/main+0x4d0810)
        #1 0x7f75529b1097  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x90097)
        #2 0x50a80f  (/home/adacosta/WORK/fffffffffff/Sanitazer/build/src/main+0x50a80f)
        #3 0x7f7550369f29  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20f29)

    Indirect leak of 4239 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
        #0 0x4d0c35  (/home/adacosta/WORK/fffffffffff/Sanitazer/build/src/main+0x4d0c35)
        #1 0x7f754545b47c  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3+0x3247c)

    Indirect leak of 1824 byte(s) in 57 object(s) allocated from:
        #0 0x4d0a18  (/home/adacosta/WORK/fffffffffff/Sanitazer/build/src/main+0x4d0a18)
        #1 0x7f7548037fd8  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1+0x1dfd8)
.
.
.
```

As you can see I have a  "Indirect leak of" from dbus lib.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a clang question, but a cmake one. You need to learn how to pass CFLAGS per source-file. Along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638408/override-compile-flags-for-single-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Change the `set(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_TYPE "AddressSanitizer")` to
   `set(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_TYPE "LeakSanitizer")`.
2. Change the `interceptor_via_lib:dbus-1` to `leak:libdbus-1`.

This will to send `LSAN_OPTIONS` instead of `ASAN_OPTIONS` to the process execution.

More info: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer#suppressions