# returning *this gives Weffc++ warning

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, weffc++

I have some code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zKO9FF) that I am compiling with -Weffc++ -Wall -Wextra.

Basically I have this snippet:

```
class base
{};

class test : public base
{
public:
    base& operator=(int)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and I get the warning: `warning: 'operator=' should return a reference to '*this' [-Weffc++]`. I am not really sure what to make of that warning. I have read that this is perfectly ok (i.e. to return a deferenced this).

Is there a way I can keep my complier happy?

Comment: Returning a reference to `*this` is pretty common, specially when overloading operators like `operator=`.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that still gives the warning on your machine?

Comment: Is `*this` an instance of `test`?  Does not reproduce, live: https://godbolt.org/z/JvKVxq

Comment: Did a search turn up documentation on weffc's warnings list?  This is a "style police" option for g++ so these are not "real" warnings.  You need to find why Meyers considers it poor style.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - infact that is what I was doing on my linux VM

Comment: @NathanOliver I can do that, but its on a secure network so I would have to hand tpye it. I wanted to use some online tool to provide the example + warning to make it easier to show : (

Comment: @DaveS oh... some of the effc++ I thought looked quite useful.. maybe I should turn them on manually?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you are overloading `operator=` and not returning the same type as the class (meaning the code snippet you gave is irrelevant). Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/NxP0Yk) or even [this](https://godbolt.org/z/-5Kc5Z)

Comment: @Justin I will try to revise my example tomorrow based on my linux VM code... its using g++ v 7.4.0 c++11, etc...

Comment: @Justin hmm... that could be, it returns the type of the base class....ah... ok, that might be a problem!? .. gah, I will update the example when I get home in about an hour! sorry if that is it, but probably same question if/when it is :o

Comment: You shouldn't return a reference to a base class on operator=. The warning is correct and the only thing you could do about it is to either fix the code or ignore the warning.

Comment: [Keep in mind that you should also consider if you really want to use -Weffc++ at all...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11529328/3854787)

Comment: @Justin just got home... thanks for that, yes that is exactly the problem.

Comment: @CássioRenan given that I did not write this little bit of code. I am just trying to fix the warning produced by other developers... what would be your advise to fix that? - return a pointer?

Comment: either follow P.E. Normand's answer (this is what I would do if I were in your position); ignore the warning (by just leaving it there - the compiler is your servant, not your master - or using pragmas); or completely disable it (I never used it, in fact).

Comment: @CássioRenan thanks for the advice... at the moment there are only a few issues like the, but as you say, if it becomes a problem we may well disable it. But in this case I think it picked up a valid warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
class test : public base
{
public:
     test& operator=(int)
     {
        return *this;
     }
};
```

And everybody will be happy, not just your compiler.

PS: If you wish to know more the warnings produced by -Weffc++ are an extract of the recommendations found in this book :

> Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs,
>   Addison–Wesley, 1992, (ISBN 0-321-33487-6).