# How i can call enclosed class object's constructor in enclosing class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Consider this snippet of code.

```
class A{
    public:
    A(): a(10) {}
    int a ;
};
class B{
public:

    B() : A::A(){}
    A a;

};
```

Compiler gave me a warning

`error: type 'A' is not a direct base of 'B'|`

I understand the error but how i can call A's constructor in B's constructor. Any alternative.

Ik it's an  implicit call but i need an explicit call. As compiler says.

`warning: 'B::a' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|`

P.S. - Don't recommend INHERITANCE. I can't do that.

Comment: For what instance of `A` do you want to call it? For `a`? Then it's `B() : a() {}` (which is equivalent to just `B() {}`).

Comment: `a`s constructor is already called implicitly

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I want to call it explicitly in B's initializer list.

Comment: `B() : a() {}`?

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) why do you think you need to call the constructor of `A` ?

Comment: btw the term "eclosing class" is used for something else. Here `a` is simply a member of `B`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 It's not XY problem. I have enabled compiler warning and it says to initialize it in B's initializing list. And i found that irritating.

Comment: Which compiler (and which version) gives such warning? The compiler should initialize `a` with default constructor without any initializer list (and it should certainly not warn programmer about not doing what it is supposed to do).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 already told you compiler is suggesting me to do so. This is what is says it's gcc` 'B::a' should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]|`

Comment: "I have enabled compiler warning and it says to initialize it in B's initializing list. And i found that irritating."  exactly that is missing from your question to know what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @Problematic "_ I have enabled compiler warning and it says to initialize it in B's initializing list._" 1) I feel that you misunderstood the warning. If you are asking such question, because of a warning, provide the warning in your question, and we'll help you solve the warning. 2) Your such comment revealed, that it is, in fact, an XY problem.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius check comment

Comment: calm down (i did already ;). I was too fast in writing one comment (deleted by now). It is a xy problem and deniying it wont help anybody. The warning should be part of the question, because otherwise one has to wonder what the question is about

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Added :-)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There are C++ guidelines that mandate initializing all member objects either inline or in the member initializer list. Our linter at work enforces this, for example.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That's fine, but I don't know why it's part of the "effective C++" set of warnings. Compiler is obliged to initialize this member so it's neither inefficient nor dangerous to not do that. I guess it's just a part of the guidelines by Scott? It seems that [I'm not the only one who finds the behaviour of this flag weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496942/understanding-weffc)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen One could argue that it prevents bugs due to forgetting to actually pass arguments to (default-constructable) base classes or members. I'm pretty sure it's caught the occasional problem for me. But it also creates verbosity. Whether this tradeoff is overall beneficial is debatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
class B{
public:

    B() : a(){}
    A a;

};
```

Though it is redundant because in any case the data member a will be default initialized by using the default constructor of the class A.